# VHDL - Need some advice on division & multiplication

Tags: vhdl, unsigned, division

Fellow SO users,

I'm trying to calibrate a resistive humidity sensor that I'm reading values from the ADC. The ADC outputs an 8-bit value. I'm using a Vref value of 5V.

My first step in calibrating is to divide the number by 255 and multiply by the Vref value.
Hence, calibrated value = (output / 255) * Vref.

Now, in VHDL, I've come across some VHDL code to divide two numbers. The one I have divides two unsigned numbers so that shouldn't be a problem. It is over here;
[VHDL divide two unsigned numbers](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/vhdl-function-for-division-two-signed.html)

Now, in my VHDL file, I have the 8 bit ADC value (humidity) and I have defined two constants, max_val (11111111 = 255) and Vref (00000101 = 5) both as unsigned.
I'm first converting humidity to an unsigned by using unsigned(humidity) and then passing this value and the max_num value into the division function. With the result, I'm multiplying it by Vref.

Now, my question is;

1. Is this a good approach? I.e; the way I'm dividing and multiplying.
2. How do I convert the unsigned value back into a std_logic_vector?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think it should divided by 256? Or with 255 i think your result will almost similar (note that max distance is between 255/256 and 255/255: = 0.00390625). Result will be with fixed point number. Multiply by 5: shift right 2 = multiply by 4  then add with this number (A*5 = A*4 + A), your code should like:

   A_Multiply_4 <= A&"00";
   A_Multiply_5 <= A_Multiply_4 + A;
2. To convert from unsigned to std_logic_vector (i remember it exist in std_logic_1164):

   slv_array <=  std_logic_vector(unsigned_number);

If you wanna divide by 255, i think you should divide your num by 256 and add a little number after shift:

1/255 = 1/256 + 1/x

with x = 2 power something. Shifter is the best way.

I tried with 1/3 and have to pleasant with this method.

P/s x = 2^16 and you got diff between 2 case is 5.9838388480392156862745098039216e-8. But i don't think number you want have more than 8 bit after point.

Comment: Hi Khanh, thanks so much for the suggestion. I don't quite understand you're first suggestion about multiplying by 5 first and then multiplying by 4 and adding the result. I'm very clear on the rest of your post. It's been a great help, thanks so much again!

Comment: Oh, it is easy to use. Purpose you have number X that you want to mutiply by 5: X*5=X*4 + X. X*4 is X << 2. So, you can implemented it in hardware easily.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use this code. A_x_5 = A mutiply by 5.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks so much!
One last thing; why would you not use the multiplication operation "*" in this case?

Comment: Depend on your synthesizer, the result of your multiplier may not lead to good result. If your lib is not supported, it's impossible. This way is faster and simplest way to do. You can try to use directly multiplier, but I did not recommend it. FPGA may support it but I usually work with high-speed ASIC then I really hate multiplier and divider.

Comment: There is otherway to do is using Look-up Table (it should generate ROM) for fast access.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll be using your earlier method as you suggested.